# Windows text editor with multiple screens: Sublime is blurry and not as sharp on another screen

Tags: windows-10, sublimetext3

Whenever I use sublime in a multi-screen environment, it would look really good one screen, which is usually the main laptop screen, and really bad on the other. Have a look:

[image]

[image]

I am using windows 10 and I think it might be a windows issue as I get the same problem as well with notepad++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found A way:

- Right click on the application in the task bar and click on properties (you may have to do another right click on the application itself)
- Go to the compatibility tab and check "Override high DPI scaling behaviour"
- In the dropbox under "Scaling performed by:" choose application

[image]

You'll find that the font size may change between different screens but at least it's sharp.

Comment: After almost installing an .exe, it helped me - on notepad++. Thanks!